# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^3)=L$ rigorously

Tags: analysis, limits

I've tried to prove this by epsilon-delta, but it didn't go well...

Comment: what is $f$? any function? Domain?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Generally, any inequality $|x - 0| < \delta$ will be equivalent to $|x^3 - 0| < \delta^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall \epsilon>0\,\exists \delta>0\,\forall x:\,|x|\le \delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|\le\epsilon.$$

For a given $\epsilon$ take $\delta_1=\min(\delta,1)$. After that $|x^3|<|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=L$, then $\forall \epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta_1 >0$ such that, for $x$ in the domain of $f$, if $0<\vert x-0\vert <\delta_1$, then $\vert f(x)-L \vert < \epsilon$.

To show that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x^3)=L$ it's necessary to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that, for $x$ in the domain of $f$, if $0<\vert x - 0 \vert < \delta_2$, then $\vert f(x^3)-L \vert < \epsilon$.

Take $\delta_2 = \sqrt[3]{\delta_1}>0$. Then, for $x$ in the domain of $f$, we have $0 < \vert x - 0 \vert < \delta_2 \Rightarrow 0 < \vert x^3 \vert < \delta_1 \Rightarrow \vert f(x^3)-L \vert < \epsilon$, which is what we were seeking.